# Spotlight not working properly in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

With the following code, I am using a spotlight for each item of the page.

```
<a  style="text-align:center; top:50%"data-lightbox="on" data-spotlight="on">
<img src="http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/cropped-291H-1.jpg" alt="" width="180" height="120" />
<p>Watch Episode</p> 
</a>
```

How can I actually put the paragraph on top of the image instead of letting it stay at the bottom?

Comment: What is spotlight? What does your issue look like? What do you want it to look like? You're missing vital pieces of your question for it to make sense.

Comment: how can I put the paragraph in inside the ancor tag on top of the image instead of the bottom?
WIth spotlight,when you hover or focus over anything,the transparency changes.Like when lights focus on someone when is dark.

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into your post itself. For a start, explain what on earth Spotlight is.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Aboslute positioning maybe?